# Can I prevent certain users from connecting to a calendar?

Tags: outlook, sharepoint-calendar

I have calendar.  All can view(Read).  I only want certain people to be able to add or edit events on this calendar.  I have most users in a "Read" permissions group and those who will be added events in another.  The problem is, while users in the Read group cannot add or edit events in Sharepoint, they are still able to "Connect to Outlook"  for this calendar and add events there.  Is there a way to disable the "Connect to Outlook' button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this out to confirm my assumptions. The permissions in SharePoint should be carrying through to Outlook. If the user can't add an item to the calendar in SharePoint, they shouldn't be able to add one in Outlook. Can you confirm the user can't add in SharePoint?

In my test, I added a user to the Visitors group, and specifically to the Calendar permissions as Read Only (not View).

HTH

David

Comment: Ah... I see my issue was I was logged into sharepoint as a different user as my outlook... when they both match it works as it should.  Thank you...

Comment: Excellent, please consider marking this question as answered for the community!